Why is my Python function of multiprocessing function didn't return anything
Ok, so I'm just a Middle Schooler trying to code and I wanted to make some game only using Python print display, and I need multiprocessing function, but in the function I have an input, so I need it to not be in multiprocessing or else there will be an error.
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
g = "Something from the list: "
def timer(seconds):
    print(f"Sleeping for {seconds} second(s)")
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print( )
    return "Done sleeping"
def anything(y):
    print(y)
def play(thing,harga):
        while True:
            t = thing
            price = harga[f"{thing}"]
            y = "-"
            h_1 = 54
            h = random.randint(0,h_1)
            if h == 0:
                print(f"{t:{y}<{h_1+len(t)}}")
                ans = input("Do something!:  ")
                if ans == thing:
                    print(f"Great the price is {price} Credits!")
                    return "True"
            else:
                h1 = (h_1 - h)
                print(f"{y:{y}<{h}}{t:{y}<{h1 + len(t)}}")
                ans = input("Do something!:  ")
                if ans == thing:
                    print(f"Great the price is {price} Credits!")
                    return "True"
    
def idk( ):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        list = ["Cheese","Pickle"]
        y = random.choice(list)
        anything(y)
        prilist = {"Cheese": 100,"Pickle":50}
        play(y,prilist)
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=timer,args=[3])
def play1( ):
        v = p1.start( )
        if v == "Done sleeping":
            return "Gagal"
        v2 = idk( )
        if v2 == "True":
            return "True"
        p1.join( )
print(play1( ))
        

Ok, so that is what I did. I expected that when I returned the value, it would end the function, but instead it still continued doing the other function, and after that, it printed out none. So I want the timer or the play function to end the main function after one of them ends, so they need to process at the same time.
Output:
Sleeping for 3 second(s)

Cheese

\---------------Cheese---------------------------------------Do something!:  Cheese

Great the price is 100 Credits!

None

\[Program finished\]

I really hope someone can help me, if not maybe I'm just going to make a game in Unity

Hello and welcome! We're very happy to help, but could you please format your code example correctly? The indentation is gone.

The functions running in separate functions don't directly return values to the caller. Use queues or pipes to get your data back from your subprocesses.
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
def timer(queue, seconds):
    print(f"Sleeping for {seconds} second(s)")
    time.sleep(seconds)
    queue.put("Done sleeping")
def play():
    choice_list = ["Cheese", "Pickle"]
    price_list = {"Cheese": 100, "Pickle":50}
    while True:
        item = random.choice(choice_list)
        print(f"Current item: {item}")
        ans = input("Do something!: ").strip()
        if ans == item:
            print(f"Great! The price is {price_list[item]} Credits!")
            return True
        else:
            print("Wrong guess, try again!")
def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    timer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=timer, args=(queue, 3))
    timer_process.start()
    timer_result = queue.get()
    print(f"Timer process returned: {timer_result}")
    game_result = play()
    if game_result:
        print("Congratulations! You guessed correctly!")
    timer_process.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


This answer does return the value, but instead it make the timer goes first and then the play, but I want it to be both process at the same time, where if the timer ends or the play ends it will all ends, just like timer to a bomb
